# Test Connection over Wifi only iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, wifi

I have a method implemented thats tests the internet connection in my iOS app. The problem is, I only want the method to test the internet connection over wifi, not cellular. How do I do that? :-) PS I'm using the latest version of Xcode & iOS 6.

```
NSURL *scriptUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.247.245.87/stores/test.html"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl];
if (data != nil){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Success"
                                                   message: @"You're connected to the server"
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle: @"Close"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

//Show Alert On The View
[alert show];
}

else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Connection Failed"
                                                   message: @"Please connect to network and try again"
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle: @"Close"
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

//Show Alert On The View
[alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into the Reachability class?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

It will probably provide you with a lot more flexibility and why roll your own if Apple has already done the work :)  Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that but it looks as though its not compatible with the newer version of Xcode. All it did was give me compiler errors :-(

Comment: I'm using it.  Now if you have an ARC project, you may have to go in and do some tweaking.

Comment: Im getting these errors. ANy thoughts?
`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TCViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @CharlesVincent You can disable ARC on the reachability classes by adding the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` to reachability.m in your build phases. Or, you could download [this version](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) of reachability modified for ARC compliance.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Thanks for the tip! Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Check  [Tony Million Reachability class](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

There must be a `isReachableViaWiFi` method you can check wifi only

```
// allocate a reachability object
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// tell the reachability that we DONT want to be reachable on 3G/EDGE/CDMA
reach.reachableOnWWAN = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this similar question:

[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

The highest up voted question on that gives a github link to a neat workaround and shows you if the internet connection is active via wifi or WWAN (cellular)

Comment: I tried that as well. All it did was give me compiler errors.

Comment: I will try this again. Lets see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking providing facility to check network connectivity -

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager().setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock { (status: AFNetworkReachabilityStatus) -> Void in
        // check your connectivity...
    }
```